# Как правильно создать пользователя с правами только на одну БД?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Делаю вот так:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
mysql> create database your_db_name;
mysql> grant usage on *.* to your_user@localhost identified by 'your_user_password';
mysql> grant all privileges on your_db_name.* to your_user@localhost ;
```

Что делает третья строка? А именно, что есть `*.*`, и что есть `db_name.*`?

Как правильно создавать пользователя mysql с правами только на одну БД?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из [доки](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/grant/):

```
priv_level: {
    *   
| *.*
| db_name.*
| db_name.tbl_name
| tbl_name
| db_name.routine_name
}
```

> **Privilege Levels**
>
> Privileges can be set globally, for an entire database, for a table or
>   routine, or for individual columns in a table. Certain privileges can
>   only be set at certain levels.

- > **Global privileges** are granted using `*.*` for priv_level. Global
  >   privileges include privileges to administer the database and manage
  >   user accounts, as well as privileges for all tables, functions, and
  >   procedures. Global privileges are stored in the mysql.user table.
- > **Database privileges** are granted using `db_name.*` for priv_level, or
  >   using just `*` to use default database. Database privileges include
  >   privileges to create tables and functions, as well as privileges for
  >   all tables, functions, and procedures in the database. Database
  >   privileges are stored in the mysql.db table. Table privileges are
  >   granted using db_name.tbl_name for priv_level, or using just tbl_name
  >   to specify a table in the default database. The TABLE keyword is
  >   optional.
- > **Table privileges** include the ability to select and change
  >   data in the table. Certain table privileges can be granted for
  >   individual columns.
- > **Column privileges** are granted by specifying a
  >   table for priv_level and providing a column list after the privilege
  >   type. They allow you to control exactly which columns in a table users
  >   can select and change.
- > **Function privileges** are granted using FUNCTION
  >   `db_name.routine_name` for priv_level, or using just FUNCTION
  >   routine_name to specify a function in the default database.
- > **Procedure privileges** are granted using PROCEDURE `db_name.routine_name` for
  >   priv_level, or using just PROCEDURE routine_name to specify a
  >   procedure in the default database.

---

> А именно что есть *.*, и что есть db_name.*?

`*.*` - все объекты во всех БД (в данном экземпляре)

> Как правильно создавать пользователя mysql с правами на одну только
>   базу данных?

```
grant usage on db_name.* to your_user@localhost identified by 'your_user_password';
```

или если нужно дать все права в одной базе:

```
grant all privileges on db_name.* to your_user@localhost identified by 'user_password';
```